# Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') Expression: "user.company.name"

Tags: alpine.js

please am new to **Alpine js** and I don't know what am getting wrong, am making a request to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 and storing the JSON response to user. am able to access the user with x-text but get an error when I try to access an object within the user object

this is my js and html

Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
Expression: "user.company.name"

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
at eval (eval at

```js
  function data() {
         return {
             user: '',
             data() {
                 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .then(json => this.user = json)
             },
         }
     }
```

```html
<div x-data="data()" x-init="initData()">
  <span x-text="user.company.name"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `user` is empty on pageload. Your data has not been processed yet. Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
user?.company?.name; // Results in 'undefined' before data is loaded
user?.company?.name || 'placeholder'; // Results in "placeholder" before data is loaded
```

Once your data is loaded and `user` is populated, your `x-text` should display accordingly

Comment: That is not a solution

Comment: @bora89 And how is it not? Clearly he wants the data populated from a request. You can code it in many different ways; default values, checking if the user is an object, etc. This is simply the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 2):

@Yinci's answer is good. Here's a different way to tackle it. You could assign a null value to 'user' and then do conditional rendering. When the user object is truthy it will appear. Here's a short snippet of something similar

```
  <div x-data="theApp()" x-init="fetchStuff()">
    <ul>
      <template x-if="theData">
        <template x-for="stock in theData.data.stockList">
          <li><span x-text="stock.symbol"></span> ~ <span x-text="stock.currency"></span></li>
        </template>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>

<script>
    function theApp() {
      return {
        theData: null,
        fetchStuff() {
          fetch("http://localhost:8080")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.theData = data;
          });
        } 
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Bang! That is the solution! You are genius, simply genius!